# Problem with initial condition while solving a 1D heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

So I was solving the 1D heat equation with time-dependent boundary conditions and zero initial condition:

PDE: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}$
BC: $u(0,t)=A(t)$, $u(L,t)=B(t)$
IC: $u(x,0)=0$

So I went about solving this with separation of variables
$u(x,t) = \phi (x)h(t)$

to get the ODE's
$\frac{1}{kh}\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\phi}\frac{\partial^{2} \phi}{\partial x^{2}} = -\lambda$

solving for $\phi(x)$ I get
$\phi(x) = c_{1}\sin x\sqrt{\lambda} + c_{2}\cos x\sqrt{\lambda}$

and using $\phi(0)=A(t)$ and $\phi(L)=B(t)$ I solved for the constants:

$c_{2} = A(t)$ and $c_{1} = \frac{B(t)-A(t)\cos L\sqrt{\lambda}}{\sin L\sqrt{\lambda}}$

solving for $h(t)$ is fairly simple, and I get $h(t) = c_{h}\exp{-\lambda kt}$
then I put together $u(x,t) = \phi (x)h(t)$ and get

$u(x,t) = c_{h}\exp{-\lambda kt}[\frac{B(t)-A(t)\cos L\sqrt{\lambda}}{\sin L\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin x\sqrt{\lambda} + A(t)\cos x\sqrt{\lambda}]$

using $u(x,0) = 0 $ I should be able to solve for $c_{h}$, but that gets me that $c_{h} = 0$ and then $u(x,t) = 0$. Is the function $u(x,t)$ actually zero in this case, because of the initial condition, or did I just do something wrong while solving for $u(x,t)$? I've only ever done this problem when the initial condition was along the lines of $u(x,0)=f(x)$, which gives a non-zero solution.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you assume your solution is separable. Separation of variables is powerful for PDEs like this not because the solutions are generally separable (they aren't), but because the solutions to the IV-BV problem can often be written as a sum of many separable solutions to the PDE. In the more typical problem of fixed boundaries and space dependent initial conditions, you have Fourier Series as a tool to construct this sum. In this case, you'll need to do something different.